# Pivot or transpose in SQL or Pandas

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a table of the form:

`item_code | attribute | time_offset | mean | median | description | ...`

The attribute column has one of 40 possible values and the time_offset column can be an integer from 0 to 20.
I want to transform this table to a wide one of the form:

`item_code | <attribute1>_<time_offset1>_mean | <attribute1>_<time_offset1>_median | <attribute1>_<time_offset1>_description | <attribute1>_<time_offset1>_... | <attribute2>...`

I can do this either in SQL or in Pandas but I'm having difficulty with the fact that some of the columns are not numeric, so it is hard to come up with an aggregation function for them.

I can guarantee that each combination of item_code, attribute and time_offset will have only one row, so I do not need an aggregation function. Is there something like a `transpose` operation that will allow me to do what I am looking for?

Comment: Have you tried [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) in pandas?

Comment: pivot simply drops the non-numeric columns like description, which is unacceptable in this case.

Comment: what about pandas' [`unstack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) ?

Comment: I am trying unstack() now. It doesn't appear to drop columns, so that is good.